# ListView doesn't update Cell height in Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm trying to make an expandable ListView, but facing issues (not working) in Android and iOS (Works in UWP). Tried, many layouts and also tried to make a List inside the list and faced the same result. Android and iOS refuse to update the height of the Cell.

My Xaml

```
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding groups}"
                          IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                          HasUnevenRows="False"
                          SelectionMode="None"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"  

                           >
                        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout  Padding="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideShowItems}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label  Text="{Binding GroupKey}" HorizontalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>      
                        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <Grid Padding="0" HeightRequest="{Binding rowHeight}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                     BackgroundColor="{Binding BtnColour}"  />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>

                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Command to handle the change

```
        public Command HideShowItems => new Command(async (sender) =>
        {            
            var dropDown = sender as DropDownMenu;

            foreach(DropDownButton dr in dropDown)
            {
                if (dr.rowHeight > 0)
                {
                    while(dr.rowHeight > 0)
                    {
                        dr.rowHeight = dr.rowHeight - 5;
                        await Task.Delay(5);
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    while(dr.rowHeight < 40)
                    {
                        dr.rowHeight = dr.rowHeight + 5;
                        await Task.Delay(5);
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Tried quite a few examples found online and none seem to do it.

Still being in the learning stage, it would be helpful if you'd give a feedback when you see anything in the code that could be done better.

Many thanks!

Comment: use CollectionView.  It should be able handle dynamic sizing much better than ListView

Comment: What happens if you set your hasunevenrows to true?

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez nothing. It doesn't matter if set to "true" or "false".

Comment: @Jason I had some bad experiences with CollectionView. But I will try it on a future project, if I have the chance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to update ListView Row height, I suggest you can binding BoxView height instead of Grid.

From your code, I don't know about DropDownMenu, so I use Button click to change ListView Row, please take a look my code:

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView
            HasUnevenRows="False"
            IsGroupingEnabled="true"
            ItemsSource="{Binding groups}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <!--<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideShowItems}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>-->
                            <Label
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{Binding GroupKey}"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid
                                Padding="0"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <BoxView
                                    BackgroundColor="{Binding BtnColour}"
                                    HeightRequest="{Binding rowHeight}"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Clicked="Btn1_Clicked"
            Text="change listview row height" />
    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<GroupModel> groups { get; set; }

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        groups = new ObservableCollection<GroupModel>();
        var group1 = new GroupModel() { GroupKey = "Group 1 key" };
        var group2 = new GroupModel() { GroupKey = "Group 2 key" };
        group1.Add(new model1() { rowHeight = 20, BtnColour = Color.Red });
        group1.Add(new model1() { rowHeight = 30, BtnColour = Color.Blue });
        group1.Add(new model1() { rowHeight = 40, BtnColour = Color.Green });

        group2.Add(new model1() { rowHeight = 20, BtnColour = Color.Gray });
        group2.Add(new model1() { rowHeight = 30, BtnColour = Color.Black });
        group2.Add(new model1() { rowHeight = 50, BtnColour = Color.Gold });

        groups.Add(group1);
        groups.Add(group2);
        this.BindingContext = this;


    }

    private void Btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groups[0][0].rowHeight = 60;
    }
}


public class GroupModel:ObservableCollection<model1>
{
    public string GroupKey { get; set; }
}
public class model1:ViewModelBase
{
    private double _rowHeight;
    public double rowHeight
    {
        get { return _rowHeight; }
        set
        {
            _rowHeight = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("rowHeight");
        }
    }


    public Color BtnColour { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModelBase is the class that implementing INotifyPropertychanged interface.

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

          public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Bu. Many thanks for your reply, but that is not the result I'm looking for. The listview's row does not change height. The code I shared works this way in UWP, which I want on the other platforms as well. [Video](https://streamable.com/5u1pl)

Comment: Hi Bu! I have recreated the whole thing using basic forms and got it to work as I wanted it to. Hope someone can do this using ListView, because the code was a lot cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @Andrei, It seems that you have solved your issue? If yes, can you give one reply and mark your reply as answer, or you can mark one helpful reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.

Comment: @ Cherry Bu. I solved the issue by creating something else that does the same thing. It doesn't answer the question. Nevertheless, I will put the code up... but cannot accept any of the answers as being correct... not even mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the needed logic using other Xamarin Forms. This is not to say I have answered the question about ListView and changes will probably need to be done by the Xamarin team, but this is what I came out with to create an expandable List.

XAML

```
        <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollActivity"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" >
            <Grid x:Name="GridContent" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f0dfe2" x:Name="buttonHolder" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding sideMenu}" >
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#f0dfe2">
                                <StackLayout HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="#38292c">
                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference buttonHolder}, Path=BindingContext.ShowHideCommand}"  
                                                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>


                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Label FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  TextColor="White" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                                </StackLayout>


                                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="{Binding rowHeight}" 

                                                 BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding device}" >
                                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                            <Frame Padding="0" CornerRadius="10">
                                                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_PanUpdated_1">

                                                    </PanGestureRecognizer>
                                                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                                                <Grid HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="{Binding btnBkColour}" IsVisible="{Binding visibility}" >

                                                    <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Text="{Binding deviceTitle}" />
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    </StackLayout >

                            </StackLayout>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout >




        </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
```

Command to handle expansion

```
        public Command ShowHideCommand => new Command(async (sender) =>
        {
            var sideMenu = sender as SideMenuObject;

            if (changeTriggered == false)
            {

                changeTriggered = true;
                if (sideMenu.rowHeight > 0)
                {
                    foreach (SideMenuDevice dev in sideMenu.device)
                    {
                        dev.visibility = false;

                        while (sideMenu.rowHeight >(sideMenu.device.Count - (sideMenu.device.IndexOf(dev) + 1))*40)
                        {
                            sideMenu.rowHeight = sideMenu.rowHeight - 5;
                            await Task.Delay(5);
                        }

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (SideMenuDevice dev in sideMenu.device)
                    {
                        while (sideMenu.rowHeight <= (sideMenu.device.IndexOf(dev) +1 ) *40)
                        {
                        sideMenu.rowHeight = sideMenu.rowHeight + 5;
                        await Task.Delay(5);
                        }
                        dev.visibility = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            changeTriggered = false;
        });
```

Please give feedback, if you can!

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure that  `HasUnevenRows="true"` to your listview.HasUnevenRows property will be used to expand the cell height based on the content which is present in the cell.
2. Apply padding to Grid.
   EX:`<Grid Padding="5">`

Comment: @ Priyanka Thank you. Tested it before and doesn't work. Set to "false" only because I ran out of ideas and wanted to test.